# Openshift route to accept SMTP requests

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I want to create an Openshift route that accepts SMTP traffic.

I can do it with a nodeport but I loose the DNS and load balancing features a route offers me.

Can I just use a TCP route on port 25?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No you can't
`"Routes"`can only "listen" on ports 80 and 443

`"NodePort"`Service is the way to go here

As for DNS and load balancing, you need to use/install a load balancer in front of your cluster. OCP requires 2 in fact. One for the API and one for user traffic...

You should already have one to point to the nodes where your ingress controllers are deployed in your OCP cluster to direct the traffic to the"`Routes`"...

Also a`NodePort`service will make **all** the nodes of the cluster to listen on that port even the ones where the pods associated wit your application do not run. The traffic will be routed/dispatched from the node where the connection landed to one of the nodes where the k8s scheduler started your application pods, so the "internal load balancing"

[Official doc here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/networking/configuring_ingress_cluster_traffic/overview-traffic.html)