# How can I use OpenShift built in Ingress to expose SMTP/IMAP?

Tags: docker, openshift, imap, kubernetes-ingress

Can I use OpenShift built in Ingress operator to expose SMTP and IMAP services?

I can't use NodePort Service as I have a cluster that is setup to not expose any public node IPs, all traffic goes through a single api node (very annoying but that's the tooling I have to work with).

I can't use routes as described here: [Openshift route to accept SMTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66476306/openshift-route-to-accept-smtp-requests)

I found this but it is http based and uses routes under the covers: https://www.tutorialworks.com/openshift-ingress/

I have a [docker mailserver](https://docker-mailserver.github.io/docker-mailserver/edge/) running - SMTP send from within the cluster works fine.

What I want is an Ingress that exposes the SMTP/IMAP protocol services on standard SMTP/IMAP ports. I don't need load balancing, HA, multiple host names, etc. For IMAP I don't even need TLS (this is an internal test system).

Here's what I have tried in my mailserver namespace that yields `Couldn't connect to host, port: imap.mycluster.mycompany.com, 143;` from outside the cluster. Just trying to get IMAP working first.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mailserver-imap
  labels:
    app: mailserver
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: mailserver
  ports:
    - name: imap
      port: 143
      targetPort: imap
      protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: imap
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: mailserver-imap
      port:
        number: 143
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need direct TCP access to pods over anything other than the standard HTTP(S) ports, the recommended method is to expose the pod's `Service` object as a LoadBalancer (this is the most robust option). So your service would look more like

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mailserver-imap
  labels:
    app: mailserver
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: mailserver
  ports:
    - name: imap
      port: 143
      targetPort: imap
      protocol: TCP
```

Additional resources:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/

Answer (score 1):

Depending of your tolerance to using alpha/beta software, maybe you could be interested by the next generation of k8s ingress/route named`"Gateway API"`
This next generation ingress API addresses most of the limitations of current ingress/routes/nodeports etc

Its is currently possible to deploy a`Gateway`implementation in OCP and use it, most current ingress controller have an implementation of the API. This includes HAProxy, nginx etc...

Some pointers here:

- [Kubernetes Gateway API](https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/)
- [Implementations of Kubernetes Gateway API](https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/implementations/)
- [A Guide to using Routes, Ingress and Gateway APIs in Kubernetes without vendor lock-in](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/a-guide-to-using-routes-ingress-and-gateway-apis-in-kubernetes-without-vendor-lock-in)